# c# Builder Pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have below class which builds reference data for my app, do you think it's a good implementation of builder pattern. What can I change to improve it?

```
public class ReferenceDataBuilder
    {
        private readonly List<Task> _builderTasks;
        private IDataProvider _dataAccess;
        private ReferenceData _referenceData;
        private bool _withPersistence;
        private string _persistenceDirectory;

        public ReferenceDataBuilder(IDataProvider dataAccess)
        {
            ValidationUtils.ArgumentNotNull(dataAccess, "dataAccess");

            _dataAccess = dataAccess;

            _referenceData = new ReferenceData();
            _builderTasks = new List<Task>();
            createBuilderTasks();
        }

        public virtual ReferenceData BuildAsync()
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(_builderTasks, (task) => { task.Start(); task.Wait(); });
            return _referenceData;
        }


        private void createBuilderTasks()
        {
            _builderTasks.Add(new Task(() => _referenceData.Object1 = _dataAccess.GetObject1()));
            _builderTasks.Add(new Task(() => _referenceData.Object2 = _dataAccess.GetObject2()));
            _builderTasks.Add(new Task(() => _referenceData.Object3 = _dataAccess.GetObject3());
            _builderTasks.Add(new Task(() => _referenceData.Object4 = _dataAccess.GetObject4());
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
new ReferenceDataBuilder(dataAccess).BuildAsync();
```

Thanks

Comment: check out http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @DLeh, Don't Migrate Crap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question directly - I'm not commenting on whether or not it's good code, just whether or not it's a good implementation of the builder pattern:

It's not the builder pattern at all. The builder pattern relates to objects that have complex constructors. It separates construction of the class from the class itself.

In this case, here's your constructor:

```
_referenceData = new ReferenceData()
```

What your code is doing is retrieving data and populating this object with that data. It looks like *construction* of the object is really simple. Again, I'm only focusing on your exact question, not looking at anything else. Is it a good implementation of the builder pattern? It doesn't appear related to the builder pattern at all.